# Microsoft Edge customise landing page when opening a new tab

Tags: microsoft-edge

When I open Microsoft Edge, I see coworkers on the left, the latest OneDrive changes in the middle, and recommendations/to-do lists on the right. Can I customise this interface at all? Like creating shortcuts which look nicer than the quick links on the top?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This depends : What is your start and new pages in Edge (Settings > Start, home, and new tabs)? Please add a screenshot of this page.

Comment: There are bunch of extensions you can try and check which suits your needs the most https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/search/new%20tab?filteredAddon=0&sortBy=Relevance